# How to create beautiful alertDialog like in web(tooltip)?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I need to design something like an alert view for display password policy. But I don't know how to design like this. If press button view this kind of alert?

**My design and code**

[image]

```
 viewPolicy() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Password Policy"),
            content: Container(
              width: 10.0,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                            "Minimum Password Length : ${widget.minPwdlength}"),),],),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child:
                            Text("Minimum Password Uppercase Characters : 1"),),],),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child:
                            Text("Minimum Password lowercase Characters : 1"),),],),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text("Minimum Password Numeric Characters : 1"),),],),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text("Minimum Special Characters : 1"),),], ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          "Allowed Characters : ! @ # \$ & * ~ Password cannot contain spaces",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        ),),], ),], ), ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "OK",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ))], ); });}
```

**I need to design like this,**

[image]

---

[image: @AbdulMajeed Saad Answer look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, hope it will be helpful.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn1dy.png)

```
Dialog errorDialog = Dialog(
            //this right here
            child: Theme(
              data: ThemeData().copyWith(
                inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blueGrey[100],
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.5,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Minimum Password Length"),
                          Text(": 6")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Minimum Password Uppercase Characters"),
                          Text(": 1")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Minimum Password lowercase Characters"),
                          Text(": 1")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Minimum Password Numeric Characters"),
                          Text(": 1")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Minimum Special Characters"),
                          Text(": 1")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                "Allowed Characters:\n! @ # \$ & * ~\nPassword cannot contain spaces",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      // you can remove this Row if you don't want the ok button, the user can dismiss the dialog by pressing anywhere in the screen.
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          FlatButton(
                            child: Text(
                              "Ok",
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) => errorDialog);
```

Comment: woow..thank you so much.. I will try and let you know

Comment: Change these two lines, `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.5, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1`,........ of the container you can give fixed size or you can get the size of the screen and divided it with some numbers.. change it with something till it gets fitted. and test it with multiple devices. be aware that a lot of the devices have different resolutions.